# any p2p libraries in .net

Tags: c#, .net, p2p

looking for a p2p library for

peer to peer
and
peer to peer(S)

so far I've come across

```
Brunet http://boykin.acis.ufl.edu/wiki/index.php/Brunet   
// does not seem to have #2 above

WCF P2P  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx
// does not seem to have NAT / UPnP

OpenServer http://openserve.codeplex.com/
// not truly p2p but can be added per owner

ZK++ http://zkpp.codeplex.com/
// DC compatible, not whole lot of info though

Flowlib  http://code.google.com/p/flowlib/
// supports DC/ADC but no activity since Jan 2009 ???

NextHUB http://sourceforge.net/projects/nexthub/
// officially stopped Jan 2010 after no activity in a year !
```

so the choice is not very clear,
Any that i missed ?
Are there any commerical .net libraries ?

Any comments on the choices above from personal experience perhaps ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### MonoTorrent

MonoTorrent, a bittorrent library for .NET.

https://github.com/mono/monotorrent

Very much peer-to-peer indeed.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your application mean to do? The WCF can handle this properly and grabbing the basics will help you understand what exactly you need and if there's a perfect already available library out there for you.

Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms751502.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's also our [MsgConnect](http://www.msgconnect.com/) available. Doesn't support UPnP but one can add it himself.

Comment: from the desc here http://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/desc.php, it's pretty vanilla, some additional functions over a raw socket or use the openserver above ! Ideally looking for a current .net implementation of ADC or DC

Answer (score 0):

Mesh.NET has started recently: http://eigenein.info/mesh-net/

Comment: This site seems to be offline. :/